# Node.js & SQL Server Sequelize joining table

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I tried to set a column as foreign key but I get the error

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Wishlists__produ__03C67B1A". The conflict occurred in database "database", table "dbo.posts", column 'productid'.

The foreign key name is `productid` in `cart_table` and in the `product_table` the primary key is `productid`

```
Cart.belongsTo(Product, {foreignKey: 'productid', targetKey: 'productid'});
```

Is this even the correct way?

Scenario:

- User adds an item to cart.
- The cart table will add the item info : username (who added it), productid (same as productid{primaryKey} in produc_table)

I would to manipulate the data by joining the cart_table with the product_table so that result would be :

**cart_product_table**:

```
username: alex
cart_table.productid: 01
product_table.productid: 01
productName: Shampoo
productPrice: 12
```

Comment: do you have any record in your cart table ?

Comment: @Priyank Yes I do. When user clicks on add button, it'll add a new record containing: productid, username

Comment: @Priyank I want to combine two tables based on the productid. productid in cart table is foreignkey, and productid in product table is primary key.

Comment: Chnage 
Cart.belongsTo(Product, {foreignKey: 'productid', targetKey: 'productid'}); 
TO
Cart.belongsTo(Product, {foreignKey: 'productid', targetKey: 'productid',defaultValue : 0});

Comment: let me know  still not worked

Comment: Working Or Not ?

Comment: @Priyank Sorry for the delay. I tried it and I don't get any error anymore. It seems that successful when I enable the logging. However when log the result, I don't get the joined table.

I used this:

Cart.findAll({
    where: {
        username: 'alex'
      },
    include: [{
      model: Product,
      required: true
     }]
  }).then(item => {
        
  console.log(item);
 
  });

Comment: Update: I didn't realize the product is another object encapsulated into the result. It's working now.Thank you so much @Priyank!

Comment: i have added my answer plz upvote.

Comment: Done and selected as answers. Can you kindly help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000931/node-js-sequelize-findall-column-of-included-table-model ? @Priyank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As discussed in the comment you have data in the cart because of that you got the error.**

```
Cart.belongsTo(Product, {foreignKey: 'productid', targetKey: 'productid'});
```

**change this code with this.**

```
Cart.belongsTo(Product, {
     foreignKey: 'productid', 
     targetKey: 'productid',
     defaultValue : 0
});
```

**You have to just add default value**

Answer (score 0):

Based on your scenario, your are doing one to one mapping of `Product` to `Cart`.

You did association of Cart to Product as,

```
Cart.belongsTo(Product, {
    foreignKey: 'productid',
    targetKey: 'productid'
});
```

Similarly you have to associate Product to Cart too.

```
Product.belongsTo(Cart, {
    foreignKey: 'productid',
    sourceKey: 'productid'
});
```