# Node.js Sequelize findAll() column of included table model

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to search for the following condition in a merged table between two tables.

It should collect and return records that has the buyer `'alex'` or seller `'alex'`.
The buyer exists in `Chat` table and seller exists in `Market` table which I have included as shown below. However, I am unable to get it to work. Any ideas are welcome.

```
Chat.findAll({
        where: {
           buyer: 'alex',
               seller: 'alex'

          },
        include: [{
          model: Market,
          required: true
         }]
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

The `seller` has to be inside `Market`

```
Chat.findAll({
        where: {
           buyer: 'alex',
          },
        include: [{
          model: Market,
          required: true,
          where: {
            seller: 'alex'
          }
        }]
      })
```